# How can i get the count of the files in a folder?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How can i get the number of files in a folder on iOS?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSArray *filelist= [filemgr directoryContentsAtPath: yourPath];

int count = [filelist count];

NSLog ("%i",count);
```

Comment: `directoryContentsAtPath:` is deprecated. See @bitmapdata.com 's answer

Answer (score 8):

`directoryContentsAtPath:` is deprecated.

If you want get files count of Documents folder.

try to this.

```
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *docPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSArray *filelist= [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[docPaths objectAtIndex:0] error:nil];
int filesCount = [filelist count];
NSLog(@"filesCount:%d", filesCount);
```

Comment: Is this recursive counting?

Comment: @Patrick no this is not recursive counting.

Comment: Thanks! Quick question, is there any built-in way to filter by file type, or should I loop through and check the names?

Answer (score 6):

`- (NSArray *)directoryContentsAtPath:(NSString *)path` is deprecated.  Use `- (NSArray *)contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:(NSString *)path error:(NSError **)error` instead.  This would mean that Matt S's code from above would become:

```
NSFileManager * filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray * filelist = [filemgr directoryContentsAtPath:yourPath error:nil];
int count = [filelist count];
NSLog("%d", count);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray* files = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath:DIRECTORY];
NSLog(@"%d",[files count]);
```